# PHP Mail() error using fakemail and WAMP

Tags: php, email, sendmail

im trying to send an email using localhost in a WAMP server and using this fakemail from this tutorial. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qXvGKnWXH5A but i got an error.

Here is my error, Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

How do i fix it? Im really having a hard time sending mails using WAMP and it is because i have no idea how.

here is my mail function in my php.ini

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 465

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = you@yourdomain

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path ="C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t -1"

; Force the addition of the specified parameters to be passed as extra parameters
; to the sendmail binary. These parameters will always replace the value of
; the 5th parameter to mail(), even in safe mode.
;mail.force_extra_parameters =

; Add X-PHP-Originating-Script: that will include uid of the script followed by the filename
mail.add_x_header = On

; Log all mail() calls including the full path of the script, line #, to address and headers
;mail.log =
```

and here is my sendmail.ini

```
; configuration for fake sendmail

; if this file doesn't exist, sendmail.exe will look for the settings in
; the registry, under HKLM\Software\Sendmail

[sendmail]

; you must change mail.mydomain.com to your smtp server,
; or to IIS's "pickup" directory.  (generally C:\Inetpub\mailroot\Pickup)
; emails delivered via IIS's pickup directory cause sendmail to
; run quicker, but you won't get error messages back to the calling
; application.

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com

; smtp port (normally 25)

smtp_port=465

; SMTPS (SSL) support
;   auto = use SSL for port 465, otherwise try to use TLS
;   ssl  = alway use SSL
;   tls  = always use TLS
;   none = never try to use SSL

smtp_ssl=auto

; the default domain for this server will be read from the registry
; this will be appended to email addresses when one isn't provided
; if you want to override the value in the registry, uncomment and modify

;default_domain=mydomain.com

; log smtp errors to error.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable logging

error_logfile=error.log

; create debug log as debug.log (defaults to same directory as sendmail.exe)
; uncomment to enable debugging

;debug_logfile=debug.log

; if your smtp server requires authentication, modify the following two lines

auth_username=xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
auth_password=xxxxxxxx

; if your smtp server uses pop3 before smtp authentication, modify the 
; following three lines.  do not enable unless it is required.

pop3_server=
pop3_username=
pop3_password=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "MAIL FROM" command, it won't modify 
; the "From: " header of the message content

force_sender=

; force the sender to always be the following email address
; this will only affect the "RCTP TO" command, it won't modify 
; the "To: " header of the message content

force_recipient=

; sendmail will use your hostname and your default_domain in the ehlo/helo
; smtp greeting.  you can manually set the ehlo/helo name if required

hostname=localhost
```

I followed the procedure in the video but i still get this error.

and here is my sendmail.php

```
<?php
$to = 'xxxxxxxx@live.com';
$subject = 'Testing Sendmail.exe';
$message = 'hahahahahahahhahaxxxxxx';
$headers = 'From HAHAHA';
if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
    echo "email sent";
}
else{
    echo "email sending failed";
}
?>
```

please help me with this email function on php. im really having a hard time making it work, i am using WAMP and i can't host my site yet, so i need to send mails from the localhost.

Comment: Did you reset WAMPP after you edited php.ini?

Comment: agree with @Davide Pastore you will need to restart settings to take changes. Good thing you have sendmail installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining your error:

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "" port 25, verify
>   your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

it seems you didn't restart WAMPP (Apache) after you've changed php.ini file.

Comment: Something's happening but i don't know what. i restarted my wamp server, and runned the sendmail.php again, but this time, it just keeps loading and nothing's happening.

Comment: Check if the email was received. Check **Spam** too.

Comment: I haven't received the mail yet.

Comment: Check that you're using the correct SMTP port for your ISP.

Comment: How would i know that? sorry im new with this and i have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Google it. Search something like "<your ISP> SMTP port". Replace "<your ISP>" with your ISP name. You'll find it.

Comment: Okay, something happened, this error occured, Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. xf1sm12143038pbb.18 - gsmtp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63424/discussion-between-user3927531-and-davide-pastore).